# I cant remove the big white space under <html> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to display a navbar with a fullscreen caursel, in desktop screen all work well but in small screens appear a white space under carousel.

screen of the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBIYS.jpg

I searched a solution all the day but I didnt find a solution...I never seen a problem like this :/

this is my code:

```css
html{
   height:100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
p.small {
  font-size: 16px;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active,
a.active {
  color: #18BC9C;
  outline: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img-centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*CAROUSEL HOMEPAGE*/


.carousel .item {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; /*slider width*/
    max-height: 100vh;

}
.carousel .item img {
    width: 100%; /*img width*/
}



.carousel-indicators {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    right: 2% !important;
    left: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 3.75rem;
    margin-right: 5.83333rem;
}

.carousel-indicators--round li {

    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 1px 3px; /*top,right,bot.left*/
    height: 10px;
    max-width: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-color: #FF7F50 !important;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: white !important;
    max-width: 15px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    height: 12px;
}



/*full width container*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel .item{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  .carousel-indicators{
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

}

/*END CAROUSEL*/







/*NAVBAR*/
.drop{
  color:white !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:focus {
    background-color: #DC143C;
    color: white;
}
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #DC143C;
    display: block;
}

.navbar-custom {
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-custom a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #DC143C;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.active {
  color: #DC143C;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a {

  color: #DC143C;

}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  background-color: #DC143C;
  outline: none;

}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li a:active {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #DC143C;
  background: white;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav li.active a:active {
  color: white;
  background: #DC143C;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  color: #DC143C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-color: red;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #DC143C;
  color: white;
  border-color: #DC143C;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-custom {
    padding: 0px 0;
    -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: padding 0.3s;
    transition: padding 0.3s;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .navbar-custom.affix {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .navbar-custom.affix .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  li.dropdown:active > .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #DC143C;
      display: block;
  }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form{
  background-color: white;
}

/*END NAVBAR*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ita">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Immobiliare</title>

    <!-- Includo le librerie di bootstrap -->
    <link href="librerie_font/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Includo il css generale -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Includo i font -->
    <link href="librerie_font/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-imm">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> MENU <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">ICONA</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-imm">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#">Chi Siamo</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Case <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class = "drop" href="#">IN VENDITA</a></li>
                        <li><a class = "drop" href="#">IN AFFITTO</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#contact">Progetti</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#contact">Partecipazioni</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>



    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      
        <div id="sliderHomePage" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators--round right-0">
            <li data-target="#sliderHomePage" data-slide-to="0" class="active ind-c"></li>
            <li data-target="#sliderHomePage" data-slide-to="1" class = "ind-c"></li>
            <li data-target="#sliderHomePage" data-slide-to="2" class = "ind-c" </li>
          </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item">
                        <img src="img/img01.jpg" alt="Slide1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/img01.jpg" alt="Slide2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/img01.jpg" alt="Slide3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


    </header>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/freelancer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Activate Carousel
         $("#sliderHomePage").carousel("cycle");

    </script>
    <script>

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I really don't know how to figure out :/

Thanks guys :)

Comment: ..I don't get what big white space you mean. Can you provide an "expected result" somehow?

Comment: Did you see the imgur image? The expected result is a fullscreen Carousel even in the small screens

Comment: Yeah I've seen the imgur image. Since the code snippet is not really working well, can you add another imgur image of the large/working screen?

Comment: yes, this is a desktop view;  https://imgur.com/a/RLiNY

Comment: this is simply because you don't have content ... you expect what ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I expect that the carousel cover all the screen in small screens too like in large screen

Comment: Try chaging `max-height` to `height` in `@media (max-width: 767px) .carousel .item`. Also try interchaging `%` with `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height). Maybe you'll get your desired output.

Comment: The only thing that append is that the carousel indicators are gone down but the image didnt move.. :/

Comment: The image you are using has to be shrunk in height as it shrinks to fit the width of the view. Therefore, you will have empty space on the screen. The image cannot fill to the bottom of the screen on a small device without either 1. stretching it, or 2. have the height set to 100%, and let the width adjust accordingly. The second option would mean scrolling left to right to see the whole image.

Comment: So which is the best way to display a full screen carousel in small screens?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.carousel .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

You can get carousel in full mobile screen but carousel images will get distorted.

Comment: Thanks! But there are a solution to dont get the img distorted?

Comment: Try `width: auto;` or `height: auto;` or change `width` to `min-width`.